# Create dictionary with values that inherit from a superclass

Tags: swift

I have multiple classes inheriting from a single class, is it possible to  create a dictionary map for them? So I can reference the correct class given a string key.

```swift
let map = [String: EngineView] = [
  "google": GoogleView,
  "duckduckgo": DuckDuckGoView
]
```

`GoogleView` and `DuckDuckGoView` both subclass `EngineView` but XCode complains:

"Cannot convert value of type 'GoogleView.Type' to expected dictionary value type 'EngineView'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `GoogleView` and `DuckDuckGoView` inherit from `EngineView` you can do something like this:

```
let map = [String: EngineView.Type] = [
  "google": GoogleView.self,
  "duckduckgo": DuckDuckGoView.self
]
```

Usage

```
if let aClass = map["google"] {
    let instance = aClass.init()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding a initialization sample!